# Displaying an XML code in the browser

Tags: asp.net, xml, file, browser

This may be simple, although i'm having some trouble finding a solution.

When you look a .xml file in your folder, you could double click it so your main browser will display the code content of it.

I have the complete path of the xml, and I'd like to create a link in aspx (with either c# or vb.net) that redirects to the XML in the browser.

```
response.redirect("<path>")
```

--- update

it redirects to:

http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/7227/89684913.jpg

when i put my mouse over "here" there's the localhost port with / in the end (it looks for the path in the localhost)

that's why i made this question.. it has to be a different approach.

Comment: what do you mean by, it doesnt work?

Comment: Is the XML file reachable by typing in the URL directly in the browser? OR Is it a folder (containing the xml file) which is restricted and can't be accessed by the end user?

Comment: it's accessible, it's reachable through the browser when given the right path (same as i give in the redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the question, it would be easy:

```
Process.Start(<path>)
```

It worked perfectly, thank to all of you guys who have helped me!

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("QuinnDirectRequest.xml"))
    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file.xml")

    If Request.QueryString("type") = "s" Then
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
        Response.Write(xmlDoc.InnerXml)
    Else
        Response.ContentType = "application/xml"
        Response.Write(xmlDoc.InnerXml)
    End If

    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `InnerXml` from the root node and replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` in your page.

Something simple to start with:

```
Response.Write(doc.InnerXml.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;"));
```

Comment: same here.. i actually want it idented, colored and with the "collapse" and "expand" functionalities.. i actually want the browser to read it.. not just display the content (that i already do in other way)

Answer (score 0):

Once you read the contents of the file into a string, you can do something like this

```
<pre>
<%= myXmlString.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("\"", "&quot;") %>
</pre>
```

The "pre" tags will make the browser maintain the file's layout. Yeah, you could do something more sophisticated with regular expressions, but meh, sometimes something simple is all it takes ;-)

Comment: i actually want it idented, colored and with the "collapse" and "expand" functionalities.. i actually want the browser to read it.. not just display the content

Answer (score 0):

if you want to maintain the structure and whitespace of the xml document, try using the output from LINQ's XDocument.  This example shows how to load from a file

```
public string XmlFile
{
    get
    {
        return Server.MapPath("output.xml");
    }
}
```

then, in your xml output method:

```
            string xmlFromFile = string.Empty;

            XmlTextReader reader = null;
            XDocument xmlDoc = null;

            try
            {
                reader = new XmlTextReader(XmlFile);
                xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                if(reader != null)
                    reader.Close();
            }

            lblXMLoutput.Text = String.Format("<pre>{0}</pre>",
                xmlDoc.ToString().Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;"));

            this.xmlOutput.InnerHtml = xmlDoc.ToString();
```

and in your form have this code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblXMLoutput" runat="server" />
<div id="xmlOutput" runat="server" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Notice that the xmlOutput div isn't necessary.  It's just there so you can check to make sure all of your xml is output correctly.

Comment: as far as your comment about coloring and collapse/expand, you can use manoli's c# formatter (http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/) He provides the code and supports XML coloring.  That shouldn't be too hard to implement.  The collapse/expand should be interesting.

Comment: well, thank you very much, but i was looking for something more like FILE.DOUBLECLICK("XMLFILE.XML") hahah, joking.. i don't want to simulate it, and i'd like to learn it also for sometime i use it with other things (like mp3 or mp4 that the filefox and chrome have their ways of opening it) or any other thing i might need, i'm not really in need of displaying the code (but if it works the way i describe, it's gonna be added to the release, indeed, because it would be useful) it's more about learning.